# MySQL JOIN using three tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to make a query getting values from three tables. So, I'm using this:

```
SELECT 
menussite.MSS_D1sMenu, menussite.MSS_CdiVertical, 
verticais.VER_D1sVertical, 
GROUP_CONCAT(submenussite.SSS_D1sSubMenuSite) 

FROM menussite 
LEFT JOIN verticais ON verticais.VER_CdiVertical = menussite.MSS_CdiVertical 
LEFT JOIN submenussite ON submenussite.SSS_CdiMenuSite = menussite.MSS_CdiMenuSite 
ORDER BY menussite.MSS_CdiMenuSite ASC
```

The problem is that some cells are empty and the query just showed the rows that totally matches with the query. What I need to do to query not ignore other results?

**UPDATE**

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11eabb/2

Comment: Try replacing them with `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @BenM I try, but return an error

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: @Benm using LEFT OUTER JOIN return the same result than using LEFT JOIN

Comment: @BenM Here is the error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN verticais ON verticais.VER_CdiVertical = menussite.MSS_CdiVertical   ' at line 12 0.031 sec

Comment: @BenM using OUTER JOIN return the error above. Using LEFT OUTER JOIN return the same values than using LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Please put together an SQL fiddle.

Comment: @user3004794. In Mysql, LEFT JOIN is short for LEFT OUTER JOIN. They do exactly the same thing. You can either use or not use the word OUTER.

Comment: @BenM Guys, I create a fiddle with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a GROUP BY menu.menu

```
SELECT menu.menu,
       menu.vertical,
       vertical.vertical,
       GROUP_CONCAT(submenu.submenu)    
FROM menu
LEFT JOIN vertical ON vertical.id = menu.vertical     
LEFT JOIN submenu ON submenu.menu = menu.id 
GROUP BY menu.menu
ORDER BY menu.menu ASC
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11eabb/3)</kbd>

This will get you the values that have no submenus:

```
MENU    VERTICAL    GROUP_CONCAT(SUBMENU.SUBMENU)
item 1  1           submenu 1,submenu 1
item 2  0           (null)
item 3  2           (null)
item 4  0           (null)
```

Comment: @Filipe Silva it is lucky this query returns the "correct" data for columns menu.vertical and vertical.vertical read http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

try or modified this query

```
SELECT 
m.menu as a, m.vertical as b, v.vertical as c, s.submenu as d
from menu m, vertical v, submenu s where m.id=v.id and m.id=s.id
ORDER BY m.menu ASC
```

result

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11eabb/5/0

```
A     B  C  D            e  
item  1  1  vertical 1   submenu 1
item  2  0  vertical 2   submenu 1
```